# Rails: Sort Array based on an other array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to Sort Array in **Ruby on Rails** based on an other Array but still wants to keep first Array values in the result :-

```
all_countries = ["Afghanistan", "Aland Islands", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Armenien", "Australia", ....,]


gcc = ["UAE", "Saudi Arabia", "Qatar", "Bahrain", "Kuwait", "Oman"]
```

**Desired OUTPUT**:

I want to sort all countries but want GCC countries (Without Sorting - any order) to appear first, remaining countries should appear in sorting (A-Z).

```
["UAE", "Saudi Arabia", "Qatar", "Bahrain", "Kuwait", "Oman", "Afghanistan", "Aland Islands", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa" .....]
```

I can do it in following way but it doesn't seem to be very good code and break alphabetical sorting for non-gcc countries.

```
 countries.sort_by{|x| gcc.index(x) || gcc.size }
```

**Any better way to do it ?**

Comment: gcc<<all_countries(sortedarray)

Comment: The GCC countries at the beginning of your “desired output” are not sorted, despite the fact that you said you want to sort `all_countries`. Please edit to either correct the desired output or better explain how you want `all_countries` to be sorted. This is a pure-Ruby question, so you should neither mention Rails nor have a Rails tag. When giving examples it’s best for them to be complete (e.g., no ’...`), to allow readers to test their code.

Comment: @CarySwoveland there is no need to have proper order for GCC countries (if we can its fine) but for NON-GCC countries, we need to keep in order.

Comment: I've deleted my answer because I misunderstood your question. Your example is poor. `gcc` should contain just a few elements, say 3, and `all_countries` should contain perhaps 6-8 elements, *including* the elements of `gcc`. You need to state whether `all_countries` is already sorted, even though that seems to be the case from your example.

Answer (score 3):

```
gcc + (all_countries - gcc).sort
```

Comment: If, as suggested by `all_countries` in the question, `.sort` may not be necessary. Note [Array#-](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-2D) states, "The order is preserved from the original array.".

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes, probably. But with `sort` it surely works, no matter how the `all_countries` is sorted upfront.